# What is the difference between a propeller and a turbo propeller?

Tags: aircraft-design, engine

I have found the differences rather interesting between the Beechcraft Bonanza engine and a turboprop, I have heard there the same and they're different. But I need a straight answer.

Comment: By "Propeller turbine" do you mean Turboprop?  Just asking for clarification, as I've never heard the term...

Comment: Do you mean turboprop (as in turbine engine) or turbocharged piston? This question certainly parses but it makes almost no sense to me nonetheless.

Comment: You may want to edit the question to say something like "turboprop v. a piston prop", after the selected answer.  It will make the question easier to find for later users.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are trying to ask

> What is the difference between a propeller and a turbo propeller?

A traditional propeller plane is powered by an [reciprocating (piston)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocating_engine) engine. These can be in the form of radial, flat, or V style engines with a few other configurations used here and there.

[image]

On the other hand a turbo prop is a propeller plane that is powered by a [turbine engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_turbine). In this instance the shaft of the turbine is used to drive a propellor. One could think of this as putting a propellor on the front of a jet engine.
[image]

Comment: The bit about "internal combustion" engine is off. Both types are internal combustion engines, because in both cases the combustion chamber is part of the working fluid flow circuit. All kind of jet (tubrofan, turbojet, ramjet, scramjet) and rocket engines are also internal combustion engines. External combustion engine would be e.g. steam engine, but those don't have the efficiency needed for aircraft propulsion.

Comment: I would agree that in both cases the combustion is internal. In this case I am using the colloquial version of "internal combustion engine" to refer to piston engines.

Comment: @JanHudec: [Sometimes they do!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam_aircraft)